# prompt directory and md with .bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, cd

I'm making a bat file that prompts directory from user and make directory in that prompted directory

```
@echo off
set /p dir=enter directory: 
cd %dir%
cd
md assets
cd assets

md folder folder2 folder

md addons
cd addons

md folder folder2 folder
```

I put this file one desktop so when I run this file everything happens on desktop but not the directory I prompted. What should I do ?

Comment: Please give us examples of the entries that you've made at the "enter directory" prompt. It's a little difficult to look over your shoulder from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recommendation: Remove (or comment out) your `@echo off` so that you can see what it's doing when it runs.  This will likely make it immediately clear why it's not working as you expect.  Once you have it running the way you want, add `@echo off` back in.

Second recommendation: You may need some validation to ensure that your `%dir%` is usable to the `cd` command.  For example, if the `%dir%` directory doesn't actually exist, the `cd` command will fail.  Or, if your input includes a drive letter (e.g. `E:\newFolder\`) the `cd` command won't get you there unless you use the `/d` switch.

Third recommendation: It's good practice to put your path names and path variables in quotes, like this:

```
set /p "dir=enter directory:"
```

Here's an alternate approach I prefer, which is to avoid `cd` in batch files altogether.  With some input validation, thrown in.

```
:SetDriveLetter
set /p "drive=enter drive letter:"
:: check for colon following drive letter, add it if it's not there
:: (add whatever other input validation you think necessary)
if not "%drive:~1%"==":" set drive=%drive%:
if not exist "%drive%\" (
    echo invalid drive. 
    goto SetDriveLetter
)
:SetDirectory
set /p "dir=enter directory:"
:: check for backslash preceding the directory, remove it if it's there
:: (add whatever other input validation you think necessary)
if ^%dir:~0,1%==^\ set dir=%dir:~1%
echo This will create folders in %drive%\%dir%\  
choice /m "Continue with this operation?"
if errorlevel 2 (
    echo Operation cancelled by user.
    goto End
)
:: You can use the `md` command to create multiple directories in one line.
:: I prefer to separate them out, one per line, for better readability.  
md "%drive%\%dir%\assets
md "%drive%\%dir%\assets\folder" 
md "%drive%\%dir%\assets\folder2" 
md "%drive%\%dir%\assets\addons"
md "%drive%\%dir%\assets\addons\folder" 
md "%drive%\%dir%\assets\addons\folder2"

:End
```

Comment: Thank you, I have never really used cmd before, this is all I know. However, I tried to run your code and it doesn't work, I think the problem starts from `choice` in `SetDirectory`

Comment: @user3761386 Oops.  I had a couple mistakes in there.  I fixed them.